# Не работает класс form-inline

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Пытаюсь сделать в навбаре горизонтальную форму. В документации Bootstrap 4 указано что можно использовать класс form-inline, я пробую, но никак не получается, форма постоянно принимает вертикальный вид.

```
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Тест</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <!--<div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Главная <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Страница</a>
        </div>-->
        <form class="form-inline">
            <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext text-white" value="Иванов Иван">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-light">Выйти</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

В итоге обернул input и button в div'ы и стало отображаться как надо.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.form-inline.myform1 {
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Тест</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <!--<div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Главная <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Страница</a>
        </div>-->
    <form class="form-inline myform1">
      <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext text-white" value="Иванов Иван">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-light">Выйти</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Пробуй комбинировать со своими стилями. В данном примере добавили доп класс «myform1», в стилях пишем, то что нужно тебе:

```
.form-inline.myform1 {
flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Хотелось бы обойтись средствами бутстрапа, да и понять чтобы почему не работает как в документации

Comment: @DamirFelix Если ты будешь использовать свои комбинации вместе с бутстрапом, то так будет лучше для тебя. Во-первых, добавляя свои классы - ты не портишь тем самым ничего. Во-вторых твои знания будут лучше. Да и вообще, если будешь знать основы CSS, то и бутстрап не нужен особо.

Comment: как я понял, дело в классе form-control-plaintext у инпута, если его убрать то форма выстраивается в линию, но мне нужно чтобы данный инпут был без рамки и фона